# syntax coloring R terminal

Tags: terminal, osx, r

I use R in the terminal. I use an editor for writing the code but to test out parts of the script I use terminal as the scripts get written. Is there a way to get r session in the terminal to have R syntax highlight.

Comment: What text editor are you using? You could use a terminal based editor like `vim` or `nano`.

Comment: this is main when i am running r console on terminal

Answer (score 4):

*radian* is a modern command line interface for R:

[image: radian screenshot]

[radian: A 21 century R console](https://github.com/randy3k/radian):

> radian is an alternative console for the R program with multiline editing and rich syntax highlighting. One would consider radian as a [ipython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython) clone for R, though its design is more aligned to [julia](https://julialang.org/).

Answer (score 3):

In R session, install `colorout` package with:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("jalvesaq/colorout")
```

Add init code in `~/.Rprofile`:

```
$ cat ~/.Rprofile 
invisible(colorout::setOutputColors)
```

Sample screenshot:
[image]

ref: https://github.com/jalvesaq/colorout

**[troubleshoot]**

If you get error `Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘colorout’`, then try to reinstall R(may not necessary), backup/remove `~/.Rprofile`, then rerun `install.packages("devtools")` and following steps above.